# Uninstall Sql Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server-2008

Well, I have accidently upgraded my production server from SQL Server 2008 to SQL Server 2008 **R2**. Now when I am restoring database from production to my development computer which have SQL Server 2008, it says Restore Failed because it is not possible to restore to old version.

> The database was backed up on a server running version 10.50.1600.
>   That version is incompatible with this server, which is running
>   version 10.00.1600. Either restore the database on a server that
>   supports the backup, or use a backup that is compatible with this
>   server.

Now please let me know that can I revert back to my old SQL Server 2008? or what are other solution?

Comment: Can you upgrade your development server to SQL Server 2008 R2?

Comment: no, i can't....

Answer (score 1):

You can uninstall the wrong version and reinstall the correct one.

You can restore your server from backup.

You can put the database in compatibility mode for older versions of SQL server.